Split list into key and value by character seperator
I'm trying to split a tesseract image_to_string into a list with key and value.
I got this list at the moment, I've read into pandas but I couldn't figure it out.
List
['Max. Acc +400', 'VER +28', 'VER +10']

Expected outcome
{'Max ACC': 400, 'VER': 38}


For a better respond, next time try to show your code in the question.

Code:
from collections import Counter

strings = ["Max. Acc +400", "VER +28", "VER +10"]

counter = Counter()
for string in strings:
    key, value = string.split(" +")
    counter.update({key: int(value)})
    
print(counter)

Output:
Counter({'Max. Acc': 400, 'VER': 38})


More elegant and does not mess with white-spaces...

Very simple to use, I was wondering can you remove the dot after Max by using a .replace()?

@Tweath Sure. In that case you could do counter.update({key.replace(".", ""): int(value)}). Keep in mind, this solution assumes the numbers will always be preceded by the substring  + (space followed by plus.) If the integers can be negative, this will require some tweaking.

Considering all elements of your list is ending with numbers.

You need to loop through each value.
Split it by white-space.
The last value is your number.
Join all elements except last. That's your key.
Check if the key is in the dictionary.

If yes. Add the value to current value.
If not. Create new key with the value.



TL;DR
the_list = ['Max. Acc +400', 'VER +28', 'VER +10']

result = {}
for each in the_list:
    splited_values = each.split()
    key = " ".join(splited_values[:-1])
    value = float(splited_values[-1])
    if key not in result.keys():
        result[key] = value
    else:
        result[key] += value

print(result)

